# How to get the number of items in Page object?

Tags: django, django-pagination

I've learned a little about django pagination from here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/pagination/#page-objects

And I want to know how to get the number of items in certain Page object.

I thought a way like this : `Page.end_index() - Page.start_index() + 1`

But I think maybe it is not good or inaccurate way to get result.

Is there good way to get correct result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something vaguely similar to:

```
Paginator(query, objects_per_page, current_page_number)
```

And then pass the resulting paginator object into the template.

Inside the paginator's init you'd want to do something similar to:

```
def __init__(self, query, objects_per_page, current_page_number):
    self.total = query.count()

    self.per_page = objects_per_page
    self.current_page_number = current_page_number
    self.lower_limit = objects_per_page * current_page_number
    self.upper_limit = objects_per_page * (current_page_number + 1)

    if self.upper_limit > self.total:
        self.upper_limit = self.total

    self.objects = query[self.lower_limit - 1:self.upper_limit - 1]
```

Then in the template you'd do something like this:

```
Showing {{paginator.lower_limit}}-{{paginator.upper_limit}} of {{paginator.total}}
```

I hope that gives you a general idea of how you can cleanly do this.

Answer (score 3):

In template:

```
{{ page_obj.paginator.count }} # The total number of objects, across all pages
{{ page_obj.paginator.per_page }} # The number of objects every page
{{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }} # The total number of pages.
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `len(page.object_list)` is the easiest.